# Irritating GitHub Conduit dialog opening up whenever I visit a GitHub link — can I get rid of it?

Tags: macos, unix, git, github

X-Post from a [[closed] StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20158175/irritating-github-conduit-dialog-opening-up-whenever-i-visit-a-github-link-ca).

I have a problem that sprang up out of nowhere in the past two or three days. Whenever I'm using Git in Terminal (which is pretty much always), if I visit GitHub in my browser or even visit a page that *links* to GitHub, an OSX dialogue pops up that reads

> **Github Conduit wants to use your confidential information stored in "privateKey" in your
>   keychain.**
>
> Do you want to allow access to this item?
>
> ```
> [ ? ][ Always allow ][ Deny ][ Allow ]
> ```

To begin with, I don't know what it's accessing -- my SSH key, I assume? I also don't know *why* it would try to access this information when I'm not directly interacting with Git. Worst of all, the dialogue's information button is disabled, and clicking on *any* of the options produces another dialogue box, then another, then another. After popping up some 3-10 times (it's usually on the higher end of that range) they disappear until I click another link.

What in the world is going on here? Googling has produced very little information (though it does force the dialogue to pop up over and over again) and I'm becoming a little paranoid.

**Edit**

Some additional information: I opened Activity Monitor to check out what was going on. Its parent process in launchd; when I tab to "Open Files and Ports," it lists ~30 items, beginning with

```
/Users/me/Library/Containers/com.github.GitHub.Conduit/Data
```

And including

```
/System/Library/Keychains/SystemRootCertificates.keychain
/Users/chaseries/Library/Keychains/login.keychain
```

And other keychain-ey directories (and a whole bunch of other strings of text I don't understand, including references to ReactiveCocoa and RockemSockem).

"Data" is a directory which includes an unexpected assortment of things, like a copy of my downloads folder, Photo Booth images, movies, etc. I have no idea why this file is here. I'm not well versed in this kind of stuff, to be honest, but that 'Data' dir sounded pretty strange to me, thus the edit. Any thoughts?

Comment: I'm not sure what this is, but I've noticed a GitHub Conduit process running in my Activity Monitor when I'm not doing anything with the terminal, GitHub or any other code related app. I really don't like that something is running on my machine that I am not using at all, even if it's not using very many resources. It shouldn't be there at all IMO. Would love to know more about this.

Answer (score 1):

Github Conduit seems to be a webserver installed by the Github app. It runs all the time after Github for Mac is installed, according to [this support article](https://help.github.com/articles/github-conduit/). It is not clear why it would need your confidential information. I have posted a question about the security of this approach [here](https://superuser.com/questions/844877/github-for-mac-installs-a-webserver-github-conduit-is-that-a-security-risk).